# Storing a plotly plot component as an object

Tags: r, plotly

In the example below, is there anyway to store the main plotly built component as an object:

```
library(magrittr)
library(plotly)

## this works
mtcars %>% 
  plot_ly(
    x = ~mpg,
    y = ~hp,
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "markers"
  )

## this doesn't work
plot_object <- plot_ly(
  x = ~mpg,
  y = ~hp,
  type = "scatter",
  mode = "markers"
)

mtcars %>% 
  plot_object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this:

```
plot_object <- plot_ly(
  x = ~mpg,
  y = ~hp,
  type = "scatter",
  mode = "markers"
)
```

is that it's dependent on the `mtcars` data, but it is not used here as in your first example.

So you could do this instead:

```
plot_object <- mtcars %>% plot_ly(
  x = ~mpg,
  y = ~hp,
  type = "scatter",
  mode = "markers"
)
```

If this about being able to reuse the plot, but with different data you could make it a function and pass the data as parameters.

**Update**

A generic function could look something like this:

```
plot_object <- function(x, y) {
  plot_ly(
    x = x,
    y = y,
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "markers"
  )
}

plot_object(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$hp)
```

Comment: Ugh. I'm an idiot for not seeing this simple solution. I've written thousands of functions and forgot to add the preceding data argument. I do indeed want to re-use the plot. Here's the code for doing so if you wanted to add to your answer: `
plot_object <- function(data) {data %>%  plot_ly(x = ~mpg,  y = ~hp,  type = "scatter",    mode = "markers")} mtcars %>%  plot_object`

Comment: I've updated my answer. If these plot objects are only going to use `mtcars` then the function might not be that useful. Then I would use the example without the function, but stored in a variable. If the data is going to change you can pass the `x` and `y` as parameters. This way the data you pass to the function isn't required to have `mpg` and `hp` named variables and you'll be able to switch the order of the arguments around.